# Remove older Windowsapp folder installations

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-store-app, microsoft-store

I trying to find a way to get rid of some folders from old installations. Windowsapp directory create new folder for newer app versions and keep there old ones.

With following command

> Remove-AppxPackage *FullpackageName*

im able to erase  current installation folders but same command cant remove uninstalled old ones.

Is there some way to get rid of those outdated installations?

Comment: Let Windows do this. It will delete old versions if you let it determine where to keep things. No need to manage it manually. Run Disk Cleanup (and Clean up System files) is also a helpful thing to do.

Comment: @John It does not do it. I have for example five Microsoft Solitaire Collection versions from various years all sitting in that folder, and cannot get rid of them.